# Uniqueness via Identity theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Question:

### There exists an entire function $f$ such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{i}{n^2}$ and $f(i)=1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

My answer:

$g(z)=i z^2$.
We also have $g(\frac{1}{n})=i (\frac{1}{n})^2 = \frac{i}{n^2}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $h(z)=\frac{i+1}{\sin(\pi i) }\sin(\pi z) $ .
We have $h(n)=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Define $k=g+h$. Since both $g$ and $h$ are entire, $k$ is also entire.
Moreover, 
$ k\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+h\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{i}{n^2}+0=\frac{i}{n^2}  \;\text{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N}$

$k(i)=g(i)+h(i)=-i + (i+1)=1 $

Hence $k$ can be a such function.

---

My question:

Let $f$ be another such function.

Consider 
$s(z)=f(z)-k(z)$.

Then $s$ is entire and $s(\frac{1}{n})=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The identity theorem says $s=0$ so that it seems to show the uniqueness of such function.

However, I can construct different such function, for example, 
$iz^2+\frac{i+1}{\sin(382\pi i) }\sin(382\pi z) $.

Where did i go wrong?

Comment: If the set $\{f=g\}$ has a limit point, then $f\equiv g$. But, you have $g(i)=-i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that $h(n)=0$ but $h(1/n)$ is *not* $0$ for every $n$. If it were, then the identity theorem would imply that $h\equiv 0$. 
Similarly, if $f$ were another entire function satisying $f(1/n)=i/n^2$, then the identity theorem would imply that $f=g$.

Hence, all you have to do is check $g(i)=i \cdot i^2=-i\neq 1$. We conclude that there is no entire function with the desired properties.

Comment: How stupid i am. Thanks